# Access a list nested inside a dictionary value

Tags: python, python-3.x, meraki-api

I have the following Meraki API reply for a GET request

```
[
    {
        "networkId": "N_12345",
        "serial": "Q2AB-CDEF-GHIJ",
        "uplink": "wan1",
        "ip": "8.8.8.8",
        "timeSeries": [
            {
                "ts": "2019-01-31T18:46:13Z",
                "lossPercent": 5.3,
                "latencyMs": 194.9
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

or

```
[
    {
        "networkId": "N_12345",
        "serial": "Q2AB-CDEF-GHIJ",
        "uplink": "wan1",
        "ip": "8.8.8.8",
        "timeSeries": [
            {
                "ts": "2019-01-31T18:46:13Z",
                "lossPercent": None,
                "latencyMs": 194.9
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

lossPercent is a key that takes a float or a bool value and is nested inside a list in a dictionary

I am trying to write a code to find lossPercent value> 5.00 in response_data and run:

```
import requests    
response = requests.request('GET', dev_status, headers=headers, data = payload)
response_data = json.loads(response.text)
    
    for i in range(len(response_data)):
        for p in response_data[i]['timeSeries'].values: # This is where I am stuck
            if p >5:
                try:
                    f = open("PL.txt", "a")
                    print("Serial:" + str(response_data[i]['serial']), file=f)
                    print("Uplink" + str(response_data[i]['uplink']), file=f)
                    print("IP:" + str(response_data[i]['ip']), file=f)
                    print("Time Series:" + str(response_data[i]['timeSeries']), file=f)
                    print('\n', file=f)
                    f.close()
                except KeyError:
                    continue
```

I am not sure how to proceed

Comment: `for p in response_data[i]['timeSeries']: if p['lossPercent'] > 5:`

Comment: Did you format it according to the code correctly? Obviously I can't do that throughout the comments.

Comment: if p['lossPercent'] > 5:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: Exactly. _All_ of your example data is nonetype. You gave no examples of numbers above 5 + none of them are floats or booleans

Comment: You might be able to do: `if isinstance(p['lossPercent'], float): if p['lossPercent'] > 5: ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the for-loop directly on response_data (no need to use indexes).  Since there may be several lossPercent in the time series, you'll want to use the any() function to check if any of them is larger than your 5.00 threshold.

```
for endpoint in response_data:
    if any((ts.get('lossPercent') or 0) > 5 for ts in endpoint.get('timeSeries',{})):
       with open("PL.txt", "a") as f:
           print("Serial:", endpoint.get('serial')), file=f)
           print("Uplink",endpoint.get('uplink')), file=f)
           print("IP:",endpoint.get('ip')), file=f)
           print("Time Series:",endpoint.get('timeSeries')), file=f)
           print('\n', file=f)
```

Comment: I just reviewed the output, it is returning values less than 5:
if any(ts.get('lossPercent') or 0 < 5 for ts in endpoint.get('timeSeries',{})):

Comment: It needed parentheses around the `(ts.get('lossPercent') or 0)`, my bad.  fixed it now.